# SQL server schema change

Tags: sql, sql-server, schema-design

I have a local copy of a sql server 2008 database. I'd like to know if any tables or views, schemas - not data, are out of sync with the copy on the server. Is there any easy ways to find out?

Comment: you can use this redgate tool http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio  - `SQL -> Schema Compare` and specify `Source` ant `Target` DB.

It shows all of the Schema changes and it also generates a change script for the differences.

Fast and efficient way to keep your DB in sync.